# flink kubernetes operator /docker-entrypoint default command

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, apache-flink

I am trying to do simple flink deployment using flink kubernetes operator but default or docker-entrypoint.sh I use returns following error:

Here is YAML file I use:

```yaml
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: basic-example-w-file-path
spec:
  image: flink-job-fraud-demo:latest

  flinkVersion: v1_17
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "2"
    # kubernetes.entry.path: "/docker-entrypoint.sh"

  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  job:
    jarURI: local:///home/gradle/app/lib/job.jar
    parallelism: 2
    upgradeMode: stateless
    state: running
```

```bash
kubectl logs -f pod/basic-example-w-file-path-6d48fdc87b-xlbcm

output:

/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 27: exec: kubernetes-jobmanager.sh kubernetes-application : not found


kubectl get all

output:

NAME                                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
pod/basic-example-w-file-path-6d48fdc87b-xlbcm   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1 (2s ago)      4s
pod/flink-kubernetes-operator-55f4bd64-55hd4     2/2     Running            4 (5h28m ago)   10h

......
```

By following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73607675/apache-flink-kubernetes-operator-how-to-override-the-docker-entrypoint) question and its accepted answer, I overwrite [kubernetes entrypath](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/config/#kubernetes-entry-path).

However, this time I get following from kubectl describe:

`kubectl describe pod basic-example-w-file`

```
Containers:
  flink-main-container:
    Container ID:  docker://47698da60bfdfd93c82e4677ae87121abb90b5cfeaeb2d9aa0acd078a7d39c50
    Image:         flink-job-fraud-demo:latest
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:57fdf7e046939c42e978b16f7fb85855fd431fc8d02f99c29a0b4e14587233d8
    Ports:         8081/TCP, 6123/TCP, 6124/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Command:
      /custom-docker-entrypoint.sh
    Args:
      bash
      -c
      kubernetes-jobmanager.sh kubernetes-application
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
      Message:      failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/custom-docker-entrypoint.sh": stat /custom-docker-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
      Exit Code:    127
```

Dockerfile I use:

```
FROM openjdk:11 AS job-build
WORKDIR /home/gradle/app/

COPY build.gradle settings.gradle ./
COPY gradlew ./
COPY gradle gradle
# To cause download and cache of verifyGoogleJavaFormat dependency
RUN echo "class Dummy {}" > Dummy.java
# download dependencies
RUN ./gradlew build
COPY . .
RUN rm Dummy.java
RUN ./gradlew build
RUN mv /home/gradle/app/build/libs/rrr-rule-calculation_v1*-deploy.jar /home/gradle/app/build/libs/rrr-rule-calculation_v1-deploy.jar


/release-notes/flink-1.15/#jdk-upgrade
FROM flink:1.17

COPY --from=job-build /home/gradle/app/build/libs/rrr-rule-calculation_v1-deploy.jar lib/job.jar
COPY custom-docker-entrypoint.sh /

USER flink
EXPOSE 8081 6123
ENTRYPOINT ["/custom-docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

and custom-docker-entrypoint.sh (docker-entrypoint.sh for the first case) I use:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ported from Apache Flink project

### If unspecified, the hostname of the container is taken as the JobManager address
FLINK_HOME=${FLINK_HOME:-"/opt/flink/bin"}

JOB_CLUSTER="job-cluster"
TASK_MANAGER="task-manager"

CMD="$1"
shift;

if [ "${CMD}" == "--help" -o "${CMD}" == "-h" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) (${JOB_CLUSTER}|${TASK_MANAGER})"
    exit 0
elif [ "${CMD}" == "${JOB_CLUSTER}" -o "${CMD}" == "${TASK_MANAGER}" ]; then
    echo "Starting the ${CMD}"

    if [ "${CMD}" == "${TASK_MANAGER}" ]; then
        exec $FLINK_HOME/bin/taskmanager.sh start-foreground "$@"
    else
        exec $FLINK_HOME/bin/standalone-job.sh start-foreground "$@"
    fi
fi

exec "$@"                 # --------------------  LINE 27
```

While using Minikube I do `eval $(minikube docker-env)` to use local docker image.

Comment: It seems like that entrypoint script also requires a Dockerfile `CMD`.  It looks like you might be overriding the `args:` in your Deployment spec (consider [edit]ing the question to replace the `kubectl describe` output with the YAML input) but I might guess the first word of that command is being lost when you `shift` it away.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, added yaml file. I'm not familiar with the `shift` away term.

Comment: Thank you for your time David, solved it and added solution as answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has few layers into it:

First, we simply don't use any custom docker entrypoint sh script to not override the default one in flink:1.17 image.

Second, to not face any exception such as below:
`org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not load the provided entrypoint class` make sure you copy your jar file to a valid location in the image directory structure.

Third, we follow [this](https://blogmilind.wordpress.com/2018/01/30/running-local-docker-images-in-kubernetes/) tutorial if we want to use kubernetes with local docker images (assuming we use minikube).

Here are the final configs we use:

```
FROM openjdk:11 AS job-build
WORKDIR /home/gradle/app/

COPY build.gradle settings.gradle ./
COPY gradlew ./
COPY gradle gradle
# To cause download and cache of verifyGoogleJavaFormat dependency
RUN echo "class Dummy {}" > Dummy.java
# download dependencies
RUN ./gradlew build
COPY . .
RUN rm Dummy.java
RUN ./gradlew build
RUN mv /home/gradle/app/build/libs/relynk-rule-calculation_v1*-deploy.jar /home/gradle/app/build/libs/relynk-rule-calculation_v1-deploy.jar

notes/flink-1.15/#jdk-upgrade
FROM flink:1.17

COPY --from=job-build /home/gradle/app/build/libs/relynk-rule-calculation_v1-deploy.jar /opt/flink/job.jar

USER flink
EXPOSE 8081 6123
```

```yaml
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: basic-example-w-file-path
spec:
  image: rule-calculation:v2
  imagePullPolicy: Never
  
  flinkVersion: v1_17
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "2"

  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  job:
    jarURI: local:///opt/flink/job.jar
    parallelism: 2
    upgradeMode: stateless
    state: running
```